# Accessing children in auxiliary routing : Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have `root` routing defined as

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: './module1/module1.module#Module1Module'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

the `module1.routing.ts` has:

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: SubModule1Component,
  children: [{
      path: 'mod1child1',
      component: SubMod1Child1Component
    },
    {
      path: 'mod1child2',
      component: SubMod1Child2Component,
      children: [{
          path: '',
          component: Outlet1Component,
          outlet: 'outlet1'
        },
        {
          path: 'newout1',
          component: Outlet1NewComponent,
          outlet: 'outlet1'
        },
        {
          path: '',
          component: Outlet2Component,
          outlet: 'outlet2',
          children: [{
            path: 'childoutlet2',
            component: ChildOutlet2Component,
            outlet: 'outlet2'
          }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
}, ];
```

This code works when I navigate to `/module1/mod1child2` as below:

[image]

My HTML page for above image is:

```html
<h1>Child 2</h1>

<button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'outlet1': ['newout1']}}]">Change Outlet 1</button>
<button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'outlet2': ['childoutlet2']}}]">Change Outlet 2</button>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="display: grid ;border: 1px solid red; width: 50%;height: 100px;float:left">
    <router-outlet name="outlet1"></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <div style="display: grid ;border: 1px solid green; width: 50%;height: 100px;float:left">
    <router-outlet name="outlet2"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I am unable to load**

`{ path: 'childoutlet2', component: ChildOutlet2Component , outlet: 'outlet2'}`

by clicking on :

`<button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {'outlet2': ['childoutlet2']}}]">Change Outlet 2</button>`

What am I doing wrong. I tried

```
<button [routerLink]="['/module1/mod1child2',{outlets: {'outlet2': ['childoutlet2']}}]">
   Change Outlet 2
 </button>`
```

but this doesn't seem to work as well

Comment: can you post ur code on www.stackblitz.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered that bug 2 years ago.

There's a pull request that you should definitely 1) check out, 2) upvote with a thumbsup so it eventually gets merged https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25483

I was so tired of that and didn't want to rename all the empty routes within my app in order to have that working so I ending up patching that fix from a `postinstall` hook after the npm modules have been fetched...

Far from ideal but it just works and hopefully it might be merged at some point!

Shady, but if you want to go this way too, check my comment on the PR
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25483#issuecomment-495249672

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with aux route for quite a long time now with no time frame of fixing it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726. Apparently it was fixed at one point but changes got reverted. Basically your parent path cannot be empty, you need to provide a path.

```
      {
        path: 'out2', <--- cannot be empty
        component: Outlet2Component,
        outlet: 'outlet2',
        children: [
            { path: 'childoutlet2', component: ChildOutlet2Component , outlet: 'outlet2'}
        ],
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have 2 empty path, though as @penleychan mentioned it as a bug and share the issue like, I don't consider it as a bug, rather, I feel you should give a parent `path` always rather than having empty string like `''`. You can fix it by specifying the path in the parent level.

```
     {
        path: 'mod1child2',
        component: SubMod1Child2Component,
        children: [
          { path: '', component: Outlet1Component, outlet: 'outlet1' },
          { path: 'newout1', component: Outlet1NewComponent, outlet: 'outlet1' },
          {
            path: 'childoutlet2',
            component: Outlet2Component,
            outlet: 'outlet2',
            children: [
                { path: '', component: ChildOutlet2Component , outlet: 'outlet2'}
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is a know issue when using `loadChildren` for lazy loading. But it is easily fixable, you just need to provide always a name to your default route for every new route you define. In this case

```
{
    path: 'base',
    component: SubModule1Component,
    children: [
    ...
    ]
}
```